# JAX `vjp` does not recognize cotangent argument with `custom_vjp`

Tags: python, function, jax, automatic-differentiation

I have a JAX function `cart_deriv()` which takes another function `f` and returns the Cartesian derivative of `f`, implemented as follows:

```
@partial(custom_vjp, nondiff_argnums=0)
def cart_deriv(f: Callable[..., float],
               l: int,
               R: Array
               ) -> Array:

    df = lambda R: f(l, jnp.dot(R, R))

    for i in range(l):
        df = jacrev(df)

    return df(R)


def cart_deriv_fwd(f, l, primal):

    primal_out = cart_deriv(f, l, primal)
    residual = cart_deriv(f, l+1, primal)  ## just a test

    return primal_out, residual


def cart_deriv_bwd(f, residual, cotangent):

    cotangent_out = jnp.ones(3)  ## just a test

    return (None, cotangent_out)


cart_deriv.defvjp(cart_deriv_fwd, cart_deriv_bwd)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    def test_func(l, r2):
        return l + r2

    primal_out, f_vjp = vjp(cart_deriv, 
                            jax.tree_util.Partial(test_func),
                            2,
                            jnp.array([1., 2., 3.])
                            )

    cotangent = jnp.ones((3, 3))
    cotangent_out = f_vjp(cotangent)

    print(cotangent_out[1].shape)
```

However this code produces the error:

```
TypeError: cart_deriv_bwd() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cotangent'
```

I have checked that the syntax agrees with that in the documentation. I'm wondering why the argument `cotangent` is not recognized by `vjp`, and how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `nondiff_argnums` is expected to be a sequence:

```py
@partial(custom_vjp, nondiff_argnums=(0,))
```

With this properly defined, it's better to avoid wrapping the function in `Partial`, and just pass it as a static argument by closing over it in the `vjp` call:

```py
primal_out, f_vjp = vjp(partial(cart_deriv, test_func),
                        2,
                        jnp.array([1., 2., 3.])
                        )
cotangent_out = f_vjp(jnp.ones((3, 3)))

print(*cotangent_out)
# (b'',) [1. 1. 1.]
```